# JavaScript SSE not working with Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-sent-events

I have a javascript that fires an EventSource for the page "checkMessages.php".
That page returns data only if there is something new entered in the database.

The problem here lies with Mozilla Firefox, because it does not update the SSE content whenever there is any change in the database. I checked the same with Google Chrome, and everything works absolutely fine.

Moreover, I checked an HTML5 SSE demo from http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse in Firefox, and it works. What's wrong with this code then?

index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof(EventSource)!="undefined")
{  
  var source=new EventSource("checkMessages.php");
  source.onmessage=function(event)
  {
        $("#new_message").html("Inbox"+event.data);
  }
}
else
{ 
        $("#new_message").html("HTML5 not supported");
}

</script>

<div id="new_message_container">
    <span id="new_message" onclick="readInbox($userid)">
        Inbox
    </span>
</div>
```

checkMessages.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'myfunctions.php';
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$userid=studentidOf($_SESSION['user']);
$query="Select msgby from messages where msgfor='$userid'";
$result=queryMysql($query);
$k=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($k>0)
    echo "data:($k)";

flush();
?>
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the HTTP requests and responses between FF and Chrome? If yes, did you spot any differences between them?

Comment: I checked Firebug in Mozilla, and it displays the request being sent and received. And the response it shows is :

The resource from this URL is not text: http://localhost/checkMessages.php

Comment: But did you compare the actual headers and body on the responses between those two browsers? How long does it take for your script to respond? I suspect that this might be either a timeout issue, invalid response headers being sent out (maybe from myfunctions.php) or somehow related to additional output in the response body generated by your script. Try to do the request/response debugging with a debuging proxy tool like Fiddler or Charles.

Comment: Let me check it, it'll be a minute.

Comment: No, the request and response headers are both the same for either of the browsers. And the responose body also shows the same exact text being sent. There's no difference at all. There's no additional output being generated, and "myfunctions.php" is absolutely clear. Only the data I require is being sent in both the cases.

Comment: I tried to replicate the problem with your code (minus the DB results fetching part), but I couldn't even get it to work in Chrome without adding some new lines at the end of the output. Basically I changed `echo "data:($k)";` to `echo "data:($k)\n\n";` and it started working in both FF and Chrome. So try adding some new lines and see if that fixes it in FF for you. From what I see, the [official Mozilla example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) also adds two new lines after each event.

Comment: Yes that was the fault. Adding new lines saves the day. Although I solved it yesterday itself, but saw your solution now. Could you please post your comment as answer, so I can accept it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [EventSource specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/#event-stream-interpretation) describes the following:

> The stream must then be parsed by reading everything line by line,
>   with a U+000D U+000A (CRLF) character pair,
>   a single U+000A (LF) character not preceded by a U+000D
>   (CR) character, and a single U+000D
>   (CR) character not followed by a U+000A (LF) character being
>   the ways in which a line can end.

and

> Lines must be processed, in the order they are received, as follows:
>
> - If the line is empty (a blank line): dispatch the event

This means that if the event data is not followed by a blank line, the event is not dispatched.

The fix for the PHP code above is to make sure the data line is correctly terminated and a new empty line is introduced:

```
if($k>0)
    echo "data:($k)\n\n";
```

Comment: Could you please help me with this further query? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812452/how-to-send-json-encode-data-with-html5-sse

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and adding 1 header seems to fix the Firefox problem.

```
header('Connection: keep-alive');
```