# How to send json_encode data with HTML5 SSE

Tags: javascript, php, json, html

I have a script that fires an SSE event for fetching json encoded data from online.php.
On googling, I found ways to send JSON data with sse, by introducing line-breaks.

What I am looking for is how to send JSON over SSE when the JSON array is created using PHP's json_encode() function.

I have written the following lines of code, but could anybody help me with where to add the "data: \n\n" required for SSE?

```
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
{
  var source=new EventSource("online.php");
  source.onmessage=function(event)
  {
     var data=JSON.parse(event.data);
     $("#new_message").html("Inbox"+data['total']);
  };    
}
else
{
  $("#new_message").html("HTML5 not supported");
}
</script>
```

online.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$data["total"]="hello";
echo json_encode($data);
ob_flush();
flush(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to send it in EventStream format, which in this case is just prepending it with `data:`

```
echo 'data: ' . json_encode($data) . "\n\n";
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this worked fine with Google Chrome, but had problems in Mozilla Firefox. The function gets executed in Mozilla only once, and it stops retrieving the SSE thereafter. Whereas, everything seems fine in Google CHrome.

Answer (score 5):

You can encode the `$data` array like Ryan said:

```
echo 'data: ' . json_encode($data) . "\n\n";
```

Then, client side, `event.data` will be viewed as a string, which you can then easily parse to json using query's `jQuery.parseJSON()`. so your client-side code will look something like this:

```
// Check if the browser supports SSE
if (typeof (EventSource) !== "undefined") {

              var source = new EventSource("script.php");
              // Handle evetns
              source.onmessage = function(event) {
                  // parse the data that has an object as a string
                  var msg = $.parseJSON(event.data);
                     // Do awesome code with the values inside msg
              };
        } else {
              alert("Sorry, your browser doesn't support this awesome feature!");
        }
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 2):

Your script will only show output once as it needs to have some kind of a loop to keep running (conditionally of course or you'll have millions of instances running!!).

I've chopped up an implementation I wrote earlier today which demonstrates this and also added some additional javascript/jquery to help manage the streams better. The below will also work on a single threaded PHP installation like Xampp (for local development)
Notes on Xampp: As the PHP script is in a loop and doesn't terminate immediately it will stop a new php or agax script from running. If you're using ajax as well to call PHP call stream_close() in the beforesend and stream_open() in the success callbacks.

The below is untested but it's mainly grabbed from working code so it should be fine.

```
<?
//stream.php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

stream();

function stream(){
    $data = array();
    //collect data from database or wherever to stream to browser
    //example data
        $data[0]["name"] = 'Bob';
        $data[0]["total"] = rand(0,100);
        $data[0]["name"] = 'Jane';
        $data[0]["total"] = rand(0,100);

    //maybe there is no new data so just send one new line
    //this is required to check if the connection is still alive
    if(!empty($data)){  
        echo "\n";
    }else{              //Otherwise json encode the data for output
        echo 'data: '.json_encode($data)."\n\n";
    }
    flush();            //Flush the result to the browser
    sleep(1);           //Wait a second (or what ever you like)

    //If the browser is still connected
    if(!connection_aborted() && connection_status()==0){
        stream();       //recurse the function
    }
}

?>

<script>
    var webstream = false;

    function stream_open(){
        stream_close(); //Close the stream it (in case we got here weirdly)
        if(!!window.EventSource){   //Test compatibility
            webstream = new EventSource('./stream.php');
            console.log("Stream Opened");   //Log event for testing

            webstream.addEventListener('message', function(e){
                var data = JSON.parse(e.data);  //Parse the json into an object
                process_stream(data);
            },false);

            //Cleanup after navigating away (optional)              
            $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){  
                webstream.onclose = function(){}; //delete onclose (optional)
                webstream.close();  //Close the stream
            });
        }
    }

    function stream_close(){
        if(typeof(webstream)=="object"){
            webstream.close();
            webstream = false;
            console.log("Stream Closed");   //Log event for testing
        }
    }

    function process_stream(data){
        //do something with the new data from the stream, e.g. log in console
        console.log(data);
    }


    //Optional:
    //Toggle stream on blur/focus
    //Good if the user opens multiple windows or Xampp?
        $(window).on("blur focus", function(e) {

            //get the last blur/focus event type
            var prevType = $(this).data("prevType") || null;

            if (prevType != e.type){
                console.log(e.type);    //Log event for testing (focus/blur)
                switch (e.type){
                    case "blur":
                        stream_close(); //Close stream on blur
                    break;
                    case "focus":
                        stream_open();  //Open stream on focus
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Store the last event type to data
            $(this).data("prevType", e.type);
        });

    // Optional:
    // Using idletimer plugin to close the stream in times of inactivity
    // https://github.com/thorst/jquery-idletimer/blob/master/src/idle-timer.js

        $(document).on("idle.idleTimer", function (){
            stream_close();
        });
        $(document).on("active.idleTimer", function (){
            stream_open();
        });
        $(document).idleTimer({timeout:5000}); //5 second idle timer
</script>
```