# Use Server-sent events from two scripts

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I am using SSE for my real time application. I have sort of two types of notifications I need to check on database, one type is whenever the is an update, then sent to browser(it can take 1 hour, 2 hours etc.), ant the other type is I need to take data from database every 5 seconds, so I thought would it be better to use two sse scripts for each of these my two types? or should I chec everything in one script?Wont it be very slow if I use one script only? (by the way Im using php/mysql on server side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote something on this this morning. I would use one script personally and only include the long term update conditionally in the PHP when you need it.

This should cover everything you need with a few extras.

[How to send json_encode data with HTML5 SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812452/how-to-send-json-encode-data-with-html5-sse/26051768#26051768)

Comment: Thanks man, some useful info you provided! I like the idea that when user goes to other window of his browser, the eventstream connection is aborted, and connected again when user goes back to the window. Also, could you explain in a few words how that idleTime is working? How that script knows when eventstram is inactive etc.?

Comment: Sure, idletimer is a plugin that monitors all user input from `mousemove keydown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel mousedown touchstart touchmove MSPointerDown MSPointerMove`, as soon as one of those events are triggered the timer resets. Upon expiry it simply calls a callback function of your choice, in this case it's a start/top eventstream

Comment: Wow, its seems to be very effective to not check for updates when there is no need for it, thanks Andy! Also, as I questioned, wht do you think, is it a good practice to open two EventSources to check two php scripts, where in one it would be changes in database which could occur randomly, and in other it would check every 5 second and guarantee that there will be changes every 5 sec (I want to take coordinates for my marker on google map, that will change it position every 5 secs)

Comment: I would certainly only have one stream and check both in the php script every 5 seconds. Maintaining 2 streams would add extra code that isn't needed. I deliver 4 different updated in my script: messages, task updates, notifications, online/offline and I do it every second. Just compile a multidimensional array like `$data['coords']['lat'] = 9.319772; $data['coords']['lat'] = 123.297396; $data['db']['foo'] = 'bar';`